# How should I use my accessToken returned in one async call in another async call?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm very new to flutter and API's. Here is my call to my login API which returns a successful jwt token called accessToken. I now need to use this acccessToken in the next call to create a contact. How do I get it in the create contact scope?

```
Future<void> _login() async {
bool error = false;
String errorMsg = '';

{
  setState(() {
    this._isLoading = true;
  });
  final username = 'a316';
  final password = 'a316!!';
    final accessToken = await sl
        .get<UsersApi>()

        .login(LoginUserDTO.fromJson({
      "grantType": "password",
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    }))

        .then((resp) => resp.data.accessToken)
        .catchError((e) {
      error = false;
      errorMsg = e.toString();
    });
//  print(accessToken);
}
```

And this is where I would like to use it but it is out of scope.

```
 Future<void> _makePostRequest() async {
// set up POST request arguments
String url = 'https://myUrl';
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",  "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}; 
//this is where I'd like to use it.
    String json = '{"title": "Hello", "body": "body text", "userId": 1}';
    // make POST request
    Response response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    // check the status code for the result
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    // this API passes back the id of the new item added to the body
    String body = response.body;
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in a variable:

```
var accessToken;

Future<void> _login() async {
bool error = false;
String errorMsg = '';

{
  setState(() {
    this._isLoading = true;
  });
  final username = 'a316';
  final password = 'a316!!';
  accessToken = await sl
        .get<UsersApi>()

        .login(LoginUserDTO.fromJson({
      "grantType": "password",
      "username": username,
      "password": password
    }))

        .then((resp) => resp.data.accessToken)
        .catchError((e) {
      error = false;
      errorMsg = e.toString();
    });
//  print(accessToken);
}

 Future<void> _makePostRequest() async {
// set up POST request arguments
String url = 'https://myUrl';
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json",  "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken}; 
//this is where I'd like to use it.
    String json = '{"title": "Hello", "body": "body text", "userId": 1}';
    // make POST request
    Response response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    // check the status code for the result
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    // this API passes back the id of the new item added to the body
    String body = response.body;
    
  }
```